# Table as parameter in lua

Tags: lua

I want to create a table called `contents` and pass it as a parameter into a a function called `func()`.

When I invoke this function, I want to be able to input strings into the table at the instance the function is called as follows:

```lua
function func(contents)
    contents = {}
    print(table.concat(contents, ' '))
end

func({'content1', 'content2', 'content3'})
```

The table should be created **inside** the function's scope.

Comment: I don't understand what the expected behaviour is of the function you are asking for, do you just want `func()` to return the table concatenating all values back, or do you want a list for it to keep a track of and continuously add to the list and return it? Please provide an example of what the expected behaviour is if you can.

Comment: I just want it to return the table concatenating all values back.

Comment: Why not just use `table.concat()` directly? Why do you want a new function to handle this when `table.concat` will do the same? For instance, `table.concat({"one", "two", "three"}, " ")` will return `"one two three"`.

Comment: Actually this is a demo of what I want for a larger project Iam working on and I want it to be function in that case scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is the same as simply using `table.concat()` directly itself, there is no need to define a function for it unless you want to add additional manipulation.

```lua
function func(contents)
    return table.concat(contents, " ")
end

func({"content1", "content2", "content3"}) -- This returns 'content1 content2 content3'.
```

The above is the same as:

```lua
table.concat({"content1", "content2", "content3"}, " ") -- Returns 'content1 content2 content3'.
```